The "Site Name" doesn't show up on SERPs, even through schema/h1/title has been set
The Site Name field doesn't show the correct/desired site name on Google and Bing (and may be on the other SEs as well).
I double-checked (no, probably more) the structured data has been set correctly, through manual checking and validator.schema.org.

Schema Markup Validator - on /blog/post-scarcity (the example page as shown below)
Schema Markup Validator - on /


I have other 10 sites or so, been set up for months or almost a year for some, but all of them have the same issue. (Next.js built sites and WordPress sites)
Why this thing happens? Thanks.


I assume Google will always reserve the right to display whatever in the SERPs and this includes the badge/company/site name above the SERP title. I assume they are just using the domain rather than anything else in your schema. If this is a new site, it might change with time, but I wouldn't count on Google using any of the schema markup.

Thanks @A_Patterson. The point is that 1. "been set up for months or almost a year for some" (and for the oldest one is 7 years old), for all my 10+ sites 2. Not only Google, but Bing's SERP is also. ; So I thought there's a mistake or a flaw.

Have you tried anything that Google recommends when the desired site name isn't showing?  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names#troubleshooting. I assume Google is still crawling your site regularly. I suspect Google still thinks there is a disconnect between what you are entering in schema and what they are finding on your site and the signals it is sending.

I just scanned your URL with Google's Rich Results Test tool and it couldn't find any schema on your page. I did it with both desktop and mobile inspections. I have had issues in the past with the mobile so I suggest troubleshooting how the schema is being deployed and why Google can't see it. The schema is found for tests with Schema.org. https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result?id=l5UF5vIZnN-pv58noMhINA

Thanks for the kind response, @A_Patterson. I confirmed it. I didn't know about the google rich result test. Anyways weird.. I will try inspect my sites again and see if the test shows any update. Thanks again.

Also, I was going through Google's accepted schema and, while WebSite is talked about, it isn't listed in the accepted parameters. So I don't know how much of an impact it would have...https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/search-gallery

If you have a look at https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fjpkeizai.com%2Fblog%2Fpost-scarcity, you will see that there may be at least 2 errors on the page.  It always helps to have no HTML or CSS errors.
I cant read your language to verify, however, it also helps if the title, description,  headings and content are related.
At the end of the day Google will display what it thinks is best.

I would recommend translating the titles of all pages to the local language; for example, this page with an English title should be corrected: https://jpkeizai.com/blog. I would also suggest removing English words from the OG markup as much as possible.
Additionally, I would add the hreflang attribute specifying the appropriate language; this is very likely to help.
Finally, add the site to Google Search Console, check the microdata there, as the issue might appear in that section.

Thanks @Evgeny-Yudin. There're so many I can do.. but it looks they all are worth try.

Not sure, bro. Big possibility that it will really help.
